# Is there any IDE support jump to definition and find all reference for typed racket?

Tags: lisp, racket, typed-racket

I'm come from Java ecosystem. which I refuse Lisp family is because it mainly for weak typed language in terms of team cooperation.But there are typed racket now.

For typed racket, Is there any IDE good at use type features for jump to definition and find all reference and so on? I think that is very important features to work on large project and programmer team.

Thanks

Comment: Both DrRacket (with Check Syntax turned on) and Racket-Mode for Emacs should support jump to definition and find all references. However, I think they only find all the references in the one file. It doesn't tell you if there are references in other files.

Comment: In theory, strong typed language can support find reference in whole project.Is there some under going work for typed racket?

Comment: In theory, even untyped racket could find references in the whole project, except that racket doesn't really have a notion of "this project" or "all the files in this project." When racket, DrRacket, or Emacs Racket-Mode looks at a file, it only looks at that file and its dependencies. It doesn't search outside that for "project files."

Comment: Hi, there are some aspect of find where my struct X used.It need type information.